# Display the data value after using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

This is my json
{
"message":{
"Refno":"654"
}
}
This is my jsonata file
message.{
"data":"update/add",
"Refno":($.data=update)?Refno:""
}

If in jsonata the data value is update I need a Refno is 654 otherwise it will print empty string
Please help me out above jsoncade is not working

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the proper JSONata expression for your problem:

```
message.{ "data": $$.data, "Refno": ($$.data="update" ? $.Refno : "") }
```

Note that I'm using `$$` to get the root of a document in an expression, check out https://docs.jsonata.org/programming#built-in-variables for more details.

By the way, I’ve built this solution in 2 minutes by using the [Mappings tool](https://www.stedi.com/products/mappings) that my team is building at [Stedi](https://stedi.com).

[image: A screenshot of Mappings tool developed by Stedi]

Comment: The code is not working for me the data value is not present in json